# Julia: understanding when task switching happens

Tags: asynchronous, julia

I could not find detailed documentation about the `@async` macro. From the docs about parallelism I understand that there is only one system thread used inside a Julia process and there is explicit task switching going on by the help of the `yieldto` function - correct me if I am wrong about this.

For me it is difficult to understand when exactly these task switches happen just by looking at the code, and knowing when it happens seems crucial.

As I understand a `yieldto` somewhere in the code (or in some function called by the code) needs to be there to ensure that the system is not stuck with only one task.

For example when there is a `read` operation, inside the read there probably is a `wait` call and in the implementation of `wait` there probably is a `yieldto` call. I thought that without the `yieldto` call the code would stuck in one task; however running the following example seems to prove this hypothesis wrong.

```
@async begin # Task A
    while true
        println("A")
    end    
end

while true # Task B
  println("B")
end
```

This code produces the following output

```
BA
BA
BA
...
```

It is very unclear to me where the task switching happens inside the task created by the `@async` macro in the code above.

**How can I tell about looking at some code the points where task switching happens?**

Answer (score 6):

The task switch happens inside the call to `println("A")`, which at some point calls `write(STDOUT, "A".data)`. Because `isa(STDOUT, Base.AsyncStream)` and there is no method that is more specialized, this resolves to:

```
write{T}(s::AsyncStream,a::Array{T}) at stream.jl:782
```

If you look at this method, you will notice that it calls `stream_wait(ct)` on the current task `ct`, which in turn calls `wait()`.

(Also note that `println` is not atomic, because there is a potential `wait` between writing the arguments and the newline.)

You could of course determine when stuff like that happens by looking at *all* the code involved. But I don't see why you would need to know this exactly, because, when working with parallelism, you should not depend on processes *not* switching context anyway. If you depend on a certain execution order, synchronize explicitly.

(You already kind of noted this in your question, but let me restate it here: As a rule of thumb, when using green threads, you can expect potential context switches when doing IO, because blocking for IO is a textbook example of why green threads are useful in the first place.)